# How to add an Ellipsis Button to a DataGridViewTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have unbound `DataGridView`, I have a column for particular and I would like to add an ellipsis button to the particular cell for all available rows.
Below is the screenshot of what I have so far without the ellipsis button [image]

Any help provided will be appreciated

Comment: Use `WPF`, it allows customization at that level.

Comment: Looks like Dmitry has already written all the code for you. Your only job will be translating it to VB.NET. Shouldn't be too hard, with online translators available. Or just compile it as-is to a DLL and use that DLL with your VB.NET app.